# Android select from selectors then display on map

Tags: java, android

First screen user is ask to select different buttons that are categories then after the categories are selected display the locations in a map.

For example user selects to search for restaurants and bars then click search. Then the next screen will show icons with the locations in the map.

Im confused on how to pass the data from my mainActivity to the MapActivity.

I try to do a loop for each button: but it displays all the buttons I only want to display the selected ones.

----------------Activityone----------------

```
if (toggleButton5.isChecked()) {

double point3=37326489;
double point4=-121772461;

 Bundle b = new Bundle(); // create a bundle to pass to map activity
      b.putDouble("point3",point3); // bundle the geo points for the map activity and convert to 1e6
      b.putDouble("point4",point4);
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Map.class); // create the intent to launch the map
      myIntent.putExtras(b); // attach bundle to map activity
   startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0); // start map activity
   //map things!
}
```

----------------MapAcivity----------------

```
  Bundle b = this.getIntent().getExtras();
  Drawable drawable1 = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.button_food_on);
OverlayMap itemizedoverlay2 = new OverlayMap(drawable1, this);

GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(b.getDouble("point3")),(int)   (b.getDouble("point4")));

OverlayItem overlayitem1 = new OverlayItem(point2, "", "");

  itemizedoverlay2.addOverlay(overlayitem1); 
     mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay2);
```

---

Edit:
first here is an image of the first screen:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to do a lot of things here. Parsing xml in android is not trivial. Filtering a list of displayable icons in android is not trivial. When asked individually, answers to these problems are easy to find on this website.

I'll help you with one of the trivial problems to get you started on your way, though.

The reason you're not getting the variables that you want to filter to your MapActivity is because you aren't sending them.

Before you start your intent (and after you declare it) put the variables you want to filter in an Extra, possibly as an array of strings.

```
String[] searchFilter = {"restaurants", "bars"}; //build this array of variables from your buttons, this is just a static example
Intent myIntent3 = new Intent(view.getContext(), MapActivity.class);
myIntent3.putExtra("yourFilter", searchFilter);
startActivityForResult(myIntent3, 1);
```

Then in your MapActivity you can extract that data that you sent to it from the OnCreate or OnResume function (though really you can call it anywhere inside the activity).

```
String[] filterYouJustSent = this.getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("yourFilter");
```

`filterYoujustSent` in `MapActivity` should now have `{"restaurants", "bars"}` as its data.
If you didn't attach anything to that named extra, `filterYouJustSent` will be null.

Comment: I really can't tell what's going on at all with that picture. My next piece of advice would be to open LogCat in eclipse and start checking variables with `Log.d()`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Andrew. I update the question. In the picture the user selects the categories then clicks search then the next activity will be the map displaying the categories the user selected. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you asking me to program this for you? What is wrong with your result? Is `overlayitem1` not displaying when it should? Is it still displaying all the time? Try explicitly setting the visibility of the buttons.

Comment: Ok so I created a bundle for each toggle button to pass data to mapActivity, when the toggle buttons are checked it will pass the coordinates to the mapActivity.   The problem is that it will automatically displays all the points as if all the toggle buttons were checked.  My questions is do you know of method where I can pass the data to the mapActivity. But the mapActivity will recognize which toggle button were checked.

Comment: The easiest way you pass data to an Activity is through  the `Intent.putExtra()` method as I have used above. Bundles are probably overkill for this problem. You can pass almost any variable to an activity. It sounds like you aren't even bothering to look at what data you are passing. Log what you send to MapActivity from Activityone and Log what you receive once in MapActivity. Log everything and find out where in the process it's going wrong. If you aren't using eclipse there is a command line equivalent. http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/index.html

Comment: Hi @Andrew, so im using Intent.putExtra() to pass the data to the MapActivity then I have "if" loops to represent for each button that was pressed then inside the "if" I have the coordinates to displayed. but now when I press two buttons to display in map, only one point shows. then when I press back in the emulator I can see the other point. Do you have an idea of how I can fix this? thanks

Comment: "if" statements are not loops. If you are using the "if"/"else if" format it will only run the first statement that returns true, hence only one point being showed. Please explain further what you mean by back button being pressed. Are you leaving the map activity and going back to the first screen or are you staying on the map activity?  The latter of the two means something else is very wrong with your map activity. 

Again, check with `Log.d` to make sure the values are being passed and received.

Comment: Hi @Andrew, well for example in my first activity if I pressed two buttons which means im selecting to different points to be displayed in the map. The result is that in my map Activity will display the first point, then when I press the back button it will continue in the Map Activity and it will show me the second point. I cant get to display the two points at the same time. Im only using if Statements. -thanks

Comment: @AndrewD You are calling the activity twice.